# send html email and receive it as text

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have this php code to send an HTML email :

```
 function sendEmail($to,$from,$subject,$body) {

    $To = $to;
    $Subject = $subject;
    $Message = $body;
    $from = "Do Not Reply";
    $Headers = "From: sender@taskmanager.domain.ca"." \r\n" . 
                "Reply-To: ".$from." \r\n" . 
                'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n".
                'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    mail($To, $Subject, $Message, $Headers);
}

function sendEmailUser($fromUserObj, $userInfo){
    $html="
    <html>
    <body>
        <p>
            Dear ".$userInfo["firstName"] ." ".$userInfo["lastName"]." ,</p>
        <p>
            Welcome to IT .</p>
        <p>
            Account Information:</p>
        <p>
            Username:".$userInfo["username"]."</p>
        <p>
            Password: ".$userInfo["password"]."</p>
        <p>
            You can login <a href = 'http://domain.com'>here</a> .</p></body>
        </html>";


    $subject = "subject";

    sendEmail($userInfo["email"], $subject, $html);
}
```

I receive the email normal text, with not html interpreted.

```
<html> <body> <p> Dear test lastname ,</p> <p> Welcome to IT.</p> ... </html>
```

what's wrong with my code ??
please any help I'll appreciate it.

Comment: This could also be an email client problem.

Comment: Seems ok, check the source of received email, maybe the email client is forcing plaintext?

Comment: My email client is gmail, I think it supports HTML mails. The server sends the email via gmail account also

Comment: Content-Type might be case sensitive. start both letter with Uppercase

Comment: Sorry guys, it was a very stupid mistake. The problem that I am sending the subject instead of body as wrong parameter. and the body is empty. So gmail displays subject instead of body.

Answer (score 0):

function sendEmail parameters -> ($to,$from,$subject,$body)  (4 parameters)

you are calling -> sendEmail($userInfo["email"], $subject, $html); (3 parameters)

it should be:

sendEmail($userInfo["email"], **$email_from**, $subject, $html);

Answer (score 0):

try decalring your header variable like this

```
$Headers = "From: sender@taskmanager.domain.ca"." \r\n";
$Headers .="Reply-To: ".$from." \r\n" ;
$Headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$Headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```